# Angular AEM integration usecase?

Tags: angularjs, aem

AEM itself is self reliant WCMS and can be used to generate very rich digital experiences over multiple channels.

Often there is talk of using Angular as front end and moving AEM to backseat. What is point of doing so?

1. Using angular will add additional complexity and developer has to deal with it, increasing efforts for building system.
2. It will undermine core AEM features e.g. HTL & clientlibs
3. Multi channel experience can still be achieved without angular.

Answer (score 4):

In short: there is no point in doing so when you deliver static pages, as seen in standard AEM use cases. It get's even worse: when you want to use AEM for dynamic pages, you might run into performance issues, so an external data source / index to query the "dynamic" data is almost mandatory.

I would recommend a clean separation of view and view-model using Sightly and Sling models which allow for a fast refactoring of views in case there is a good reason to migrate the frontend to a different technology / templating language.

And I am leaving out the fact that Angular will be basically replaced by Angular 2 and there are strong competitors like React, Ember etc...

Answer (score 2):

AEM's core strengths are:

- WYSIWYG
- Multiple Adobe suite integration (analytics, target etc)
- Authoring experience for MSM
- Security integration from UI to db layer

There are many more strenghts along with many weaknesses. Using Angular or other similar platforms require AEM to be used as Content as a Service (CaaS) which isn't its primary strenght yet.

Organizations that invest in AEM are mostly after the core strenghts provided by it and won't normally benefit from using AEM as a CaaS platform. Unless Adobe provides plugin model for their integration suite that can work with mainstream front wnd technologies like Angular (2) and React, it would be a very uphill task for any team to get the most out of AEM suite without missing out on all the benefits provided (at a cost) by the whole of Adobe marketing suite.

In short, from TcO perspective, these platforms are not easily compatible with AEM due to the unique nature of product which means the integration is normally a challenge and sometimes counter productive when integration benefits of the core platform are compromised.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it totally depends on the use case. I have done projects with AEM using jQuery and others using Angular. If developer knows what he/she is doing, adding angular is not much of a hassle. 2 way data binding, a clean way of doing Ajax and ease of Single Page Application, that pretty much sums it up. Works really well..

Answer (score 0):

Angular and other front-end frameworks provide the additional benefit of SPA which if integrated the right way with AEM can work wonders!

Yes, I agree that integration is an uphill task but the page load times can reduce significantly and using features like routing we can reduce the server calls for transition across the site pages.

Why AEM-Angular integration can be a good thing?

1. AEM can be used as a CaaS platform in few cases where the content will primarily be loaded using SPA. In other cases, components can be a mix of HTL and Angular where HTL can provide additional security using proper context.
2. You can pass AEM authored content to Angular directives/components as attributes and perform the desired functionality.
3. Angular can be used to build reusable components and directives on the front-end which can simply be reused across AEM components.
4. The Angular dependencies can be made a part of the AEM client library and this ensures that Angular functionality works as expected.
5. Build tools like Maven and Ant are powerful enough to support the integration. Simple tasks have to be written in pom.xml.
6. AEM 6.4 Beta has support for front-end frameworks and I have observed how fast the content load can be!
7. Other AEM integrations (Adobe Target, Adobe Campaign, Adobe Analytics) can be still leveraged in similar ways as before.
8. Did I forget JQuery? Angular and other front-end frameworks will provide cleaner and more efficient ways of doing the same things in JQuery.

The decision to use both will totally depend on the use case and this is not recommended for all solutions though.

Answer (score 0):

I have worked on AEM for more than a year. In my project, the stack was AEM, jQuery, and some 3rd party library to handle JS relevant issues(like IE support and util functions).

If you want to integrate Angular then I see the below things from your query

Good :

1. You don't need the headache of java related issues.
2. No need for more backend developers(though I am a backend developer).
3. If you do want to change some files in stage or prod environment, no need to go with java change directly package installation will work.
4. You can leverage angular strategies to build your project efficiently.
5. No need to worry about your project optimization. Angular will take care of JS library optimization and loading into client-side browser.
6. No need worry for page speed issues from google audit for your websites. That will be taken care of by Angular.
7. You will be able to achieve the hybrid model of clientlib and can avoid lot's of Js issues along with clientlib comes in to picture.
8. Testing of components will be easier.
9. AEM also follows Component similar to angular, so things can be merged based on good architecture.

Not Good:

1. sightly syntax might be underutilized.
2. Still, there will be cases you have to dependent on java for achieving some features.
3. Security issues need to be fixed as everything will be done on the client-side.
4. more issues if you are using etc/map related URLs.
5. more complexity if you follow SEO optimization standards.
6. More dispatcher configurations.
7. Needs to habituate aem structure with angular structure.
8. AEM structure will be more complex when merged with angular

I am quite new to Angular. I have written this answer based on my experience. I will keep updating if any edits required.

Answer (score 0):

Using AEM as an integration layer is a challenging decision. AEM is a content management system and works well for static content (content is cached at Dispatcher layer).
However, it use the Jetty server under the hood. Jetty uses thread pools for handling requests. It means that when the number of users increases, it use more and more resources. The situation is the same for time-consuming operations - think about API's unavailability or delays.
Instead of using AEM as an integration layer, you delegate this integration logic to more reactive systems such as Knot.x. Then AEM may serve only static pages (templates), Knot.x would fill all required data from external APIs.

See more [here](https://www.cognifide.com/our-blogs/technology/create-a-seamless-customer-experience-with-knotx).